# What is the point of G24 CFL fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led, cfl

I have 4 recessed lights in my kitchen, all of them G24 CFL sockets. The lights currently in them are very warm colored. They came with, when we bought the home.

I would like to replace them with soft white LED and preferably dimmable. However It is very hard (impossible) to find the dimmabe LED with G24 base.

How do I get rid of these G24 fixtures or convert them to a normal bulb fixture ?
Is it possible to DIY or I need a electrician ?

Comment: Replace the fixtures.

Comment: FWIW, I just googled and there are many LED options for a G24base. You probably need to look at a lamp specialty store or online, not a big box store.  However, I wouldn't take that route, I would still replace the fixtures.  Fixture replacement in fairly simply, if it's beyond your capabilities tho, just call a handyman, not necessarily an electrician.

Comment: @Tyson Thanks ! Do these fixtures have the same input voltage as the traditional ones ? or do they run on some different energy saving voltage ?

Comment: The current fixtures are ballasted, but run on the same 120v the new fixtures would.